# Add the last modified date of file to Hive external table

Tags: hive, hdfs

I have a requirement where I need to add the time the file was dropped into the HDFS folder as a column in the Hive external table.

Example: I have 2 files dropped on

- 2017-07-13  15:22
- 2017-12-13  18:31

So, my last_modified column in the Hive table should reflect 2017-07-13  15:22 for all rows from file 1 and 2017-12-13  18:31 from file 2.

Is there a way to achieve this in the external table create statement.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't come across any such feature to solve your problem. However, you can try out below steps to maintain last modified time per file in separate column:

- Create a partition table on `last_modified` column.

  ```
   CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE test (record string) PARTITIONED BY
  (last_modified string) location '<warehouse_location>/test.db/test'
  ```
- For each file add new partition to your table or load using insert statement into partition.

  ```
  ALTER TABLE test ADD PARTITION (last_modified='2017-07-13 15:22')
  location '<data-location>/newfile1/';
  ```

  create a separate temp table on new file then insert data to
  partition table:

  ```
  CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE tmp (record strin ) location '<new data location>'

  INSERT INTO TABLE test PARTITION (
  last_modified = '2017-07-13 15:22') SELECT record FROM tmp;
  ```